# Facebook graph api how to search events

Tags: facebook-graph-api, events

What are the search criteria that can be used on facebook graph API to search events :

This request :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/search?q=*&type=event
```

gets all events on the planet earth, is it possible to get geographic or date filters ?

Comment: Still no solution 6years later?

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

As you can read in the docs, you can only search by name. The only way to get events in a specific location is to search for Pages first, and list all events for the Pages you found:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/events

Comment: ok, and once I've a page id, for example from paris "110774245616525", how can I get events ? graph.facebook.com/v2.6/110774245616525/?fields=about,category,events doesn't return events

Comment: @DJousto Hi did you find a way to filter these events by geographic or date?

Comment: @jerem you cannot do that with the api

Comment: @DJousto create a facebook page and create an event for the page and it will show up with that call. you can´t just get all events for "paris", for example. that´s not a regular facebook page.

Comment: @luschn thank for your answer, I look after your previous answer and I dont understand how a Pages is related to a location.. Did you mean that I have to find Pages in my area that are organizing events and after that  retrieve from them all their events?

Comment: exactly. you can only get pages by location, as you can read in my answer. you can not directly get events by location.

Comment: I confirm, you can only search events by keyword, and you have to filter by country/place or date all the results you get in order to keep only the events of interest.

So to scrap a maximum of events I have to search a lot of keywords, I get a lot of results and after filtering I get "most" of the events I'm looking for, but with a waste of requests towards facebook graph, I do not understand the facebook graph "logic", perhaps they fight against scraping their events !!

Comment: I have an event which I can see on the web. I know the event_id by looking at the code in the browser and I can retrieve event data using the grapg api and the event_id. But the event does not show up in the search results? Do I need special permission for this? Using v2.10

Comment: maybe it is a user event?